# Encrypting large files (size approximately 100MB)

Tags: c#, streamreader, large-files

```
public byte[] Secure(byte[] Data){ 
          ....
}
```

Virtual memory cant load all bytes so dont know how to use streamReader with loop here with chunks of bytes

```
byte[] file1 = Secure(File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Switch to Streams and see the [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx) API.

Comment: "Virtual memory cant load all bytes" huh? It's 100MB, you should be able to load that easily.

Comment: Same difference. It's not a trivial amount of memory but not infeasible to buffer.

Comment: byte[] file1 = Secure(File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text));
it works with small files around 10mb.but for large file it give memory out of exception

Comment: want change this line using streamreader       byte[] file1 = Secure(File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text));